# Implementing a collapsible QML Page header

Tags: qt, qml

I've got a very basic QML Page which implements a MenuBar header, and a TableView body. I'd like to be able to toggle the visibility of the header when an image (via a MouseArea) is clicked. I'm able to achieve this with the below code, but the image is located within the body of the Page (i.e. on top of the TableView element). I want the image to sit in the top right corner of the Page, above the header. I've tried locating the Image element elsewhere in the Page structure, but I'm unable to sit it on top of the header.

```
Page {
    id: mainPage
    anchors.fill: parent

    header: MenuBar {
        //Menu items
    }

    TableView {
        anchors.fill: parent
        //TableView content
    }

    Image {
        id: toggleImage
        anchors.right: parent.right
        anchors.rightMargin: 10
        anchors.top: parent.top
        anchors.topMargin: 0
        width: 24
        height: 24
        source: "/../Images/toggleImage.svg"
        fillMode: Image.PreserveAspectFit

        MouseArea {
            anchors.fill: toggleImage
            onClicked: {
                mainPage.header.visible = !mainPage.header.visible
            }
        }
    }
}
```

With the above code, the header visibility toggles when the toggleImage is clicked, forcing the TableView to resize to fill the entire page as expected.

How can I position the toggleImage on top of the header itself? The documentation states that the "header item is positioned to the top"; does this mean that it's not possible to position an item on top of the header?

Comment: replace the header item with `RowLayout` and insert `MenuBar` and `Image` into it

Comment: That's perfect, thank you very much! I'm not sure why I didn't think of that; perhaps I thought the MenuBar type had to be within a header. I'm happy to accept your answer if you post it below.